# VueJS 3 Mobile Detection in Components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have a VueJS 3 and Vuetify application with an AppBar and various components. In my AppBar I have the following code:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
    import { computed, unref } from 'vue'
    import { useDisplay } from 'vuetify'

    const display = useDisplay();

    const isMobile = computed(() => {
      return unref(display.mobile)
    })
</script>
```

This is working great but I now need to use this in another component and I'm struggling to figure out how.

What would be the recommended way of making this available in my other components?

---

Based on Estus answer below I've tried the suggestions but everything just produces errors.

I've added his method to my AppBar:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
    import { computed, unref } from 'vue'
    import { useDisplay } from 'vuetify'

    function useMobile() {
      const display = useDisplay();

      return computed(() => {
        return unref(display.mobile)
      });
    }
</script>
```

But attempting to use this in a component as suggested:

```js
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  data: vm => ({
    mobile: useMobile(),
}),
...
</script>
```

Just produced a compiler error - `cannot find name useMobile`.

I'm clearly completely misunderstanding something fundamental here.

Answer (score 1):

Code is reused between components with custom composable:

*mobile.js*

```
export function useMobile() {
    const display = useDisplay();

    return computed(() => {
      return unref(display.mobile)
    });
    // same as
    // return display.mobile
}
```

And use it as

```
import { useMobile } from '.../mobile';
...
useMobile();
```

There may be no need to do this, as the usage isn't more concise than using the original one:

```
import { useDisplay } from 'vuetify'
...
const { mobile } = useDisplay()
```

Comment: Really appreciate the answer but I really don't understand it either. Could you expand it with some more context as to what I should be doing.

Comment: You do `const { mobile } = useDisplay()` or `const mobile = function useMobile()` you need it

Comment: Right, this still isn't making any sense to me. I think I'm using the Options API from looking at the docs.

Comment: I see. Then you may need a crash course in composition api, check the docs. The question suggests that you use Vue 2, which supports composition in the latest version with some limitations. `use...` functions are called composables and provide reusable pieces of code. Composition is supposed to replace options and it's not recommended to use it together, primarily because this is not documented and leaves you with unpredictable behaviour. In this case it's acceptable, a composable should be called in one of early lifecycles - data() or created(), e.g `data() { return { mobile: useMobile() }`

Comment: Yeah, I'm honestly just getting more confused :) I've updated my question. Appreciate your time.

Comment: You may lack some basics about JS, you need to use modules. Updated with relevant details, hope this helps

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhh. OK, now that suddenly makes a stack more sense. Thank you!